# Swift : get User Installation id to send notifications

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to send a notification to a specific user in Parse. I have read a couple questions on the subject, but can't quite get my head around it; I have this function in cloud code (javascript):

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToUser", function(request, response) {

  var senderUser = request.user;
  var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
  var message = request.params.message;

  // Validate that the sender is allowed to send to the recipient.
  // For example each user has an array of objectIds of friends
  //if (senderUser.get("friendIds").indexOf(recipientUserId) === -1) {
    //response.error("The recipient is not the sender's friend, cannot send push.");
  //}

  // Validate the message text.
  // For example make sure it is under 140 characters
  //if (message.length > 140) {
  // Truncate and add a ...
    //message = message.substring(0, 137) + "...";
  //}
  // Send the push.
  // Find devices associated with the recipient user
  var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
 recipientUser.id = recipientUserId;
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);
  // Send the push notification to results of the query
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: message
    }
  }).then(function() {
      response.success("Push was sent successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
      response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
  });
});
```

So I am trying to pass the installation in recipient UserId before calling the function in my Xcode project. At first, I thought you were supposed to use _User.objectId, but it seems you need to target installations. So I tried getting installations for specific users from my _Installation class, but I get an error saying "Clients aren't allowed to perform the find function on the installation collection".

Any idea how I am supposed to do? Should I try to get the installation in the function instead?

EDIT: After checking, it seems the issue lies with my Swift code, specifically here:

```
var sendeeInstallation = PFInstallation.query()
                    var sendeeId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
                    sendeeInstallation!.whereKey("User", equalTo: "sendeeId")
                    println("SEND INSTALLATION")
                    sendeeInstallation!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        println("FIND DONE \(results![0].objectId)")
```

The console logs "SEND INSTALLATION", but not "FIND DONE", so it seems I can't use the find function in the _Installation class. Any idea how I can get around this? I'm thinking about using a pointer in my _User class linking to _Installation, but it doesn't seem too elegant. Am I correct to assume I have to send the notification to the installation, and not the user via Cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

*Clients aren't allowed to perform the find function on the installation collection.*

Permission not enough, try to use masterKey

You can use useMasterKey:true on Push.send.  usage is as below

```
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: message
    }, useMasterKey:true 
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have edited my question as it seems the issue is with my Swift code and not the javascript server code.